# Doble consulta en un get

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Debo de hacer 2 consultar para llenar una tabla en jade pero siempre me coge la segunda consulta como hago para que me haga las 2 consultar y me llene la tabla correctamente.

```
getAnalisisDetallado: function(req, res, next) {
        console.log('Entro aqui');
        var config = require('.././database/config');

        sql.connect(config)
            .then(function() {
                var articulos = null;
                var request = new sql.Request();
                request.query("SELECT t.SI_Articulo, m.SI_Descripcion, t.SI_UM, (CASE WHEN c.SI_OV IS NOT NULL THEN '*' ELSE NULL END) AS SI_OV, t.SI_Ubicacion, t.SI_Existencia, c.SI_Cantidad, c.SI_Cantidad - t.SI_Existencia AS SI_Dif , (c.SI_Cantidad - t.SI_Existencia) * m.SI_Costo_Promedio AS SI_Dif_Dinero FROM SI_Inventario_Teorico_QAD t INNER JOIN SI_Maestro_Ref_QAD m ON m.SI_Num_Articulo = t.SI_Articulo LEFT JOIN SI_Conteo c ON c.SI_Num_Articulo = t.SI_Articulo")
                    .then(function(recordset) {
                        articulos = recordset['recordset'];
                        console.log('Recordset: ' + recordset);
                        console.log('Affected: ' + request.rowsAffected);
                        sql.close();
                        res.render('menu/analisisDetallado', { ListArticulos: articulos });

                    })
                    .catch(function(err) {
                        console.log('Request error: ' + err);
                    });

            })
            .catch(function(err) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log('SQL Connection Error: ' + err);
                }
            });

        sql.close();
        sql.connect(config)
            .then(function() {
                var request = new sql.Request();
                request.query("SELECT Sk_Codigo_Usuario from Sk_Usuarios")
                    .then(function(recordset) {
                        const usuarios = recordset['recordset'];
                        // const usu = usuarios[0];
                        console.log(usuarios);
                        console.log('yuyu: ' + recordset);
                        console.log('Affected: ' + request.rowsAffected);
                        sql.close();
                        res.render('menu/analisisDetallado', { ListArticulos: usuarios });

                    })
                    .catch(function(err) {
                        console.log('Request error: ' + err);
                    });
            })
            .catch(function(err) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log('SQL Connection Error: ' + err);
                }
            });

    }
```

este es el jade donde esta la tabla

```
  div(class="container aDetallado")
    div(class="row center span10")
      table(id="example-table" class="table table-striped table-hover table-condensed")
        thead
          tr
            th='Articulo'
            th='Descripción'
            th='Um'
            th='Ov'
            th='#Ubic'
            th='Teorico'
            th='Conteo2'
            th='Dif'
            th='Dif $'
            th='Asignar conteo'
            th='Seleccionar'
          tbody
            each Articulos in ListArticulos
              tr
                td= Articulos.SI_Articulo
                td= Articulos.SI_Descripcion
                td= Articulos.SI_UM
                td= Articulos.SI_OV
                td= Articulos.SI_Ubicacion
                td= Articulos.SI_Existencia
                td= Articulos.SI_Cantidad
                td= Articulos.SI_Dif
                td= Articulos.SI_Dif_Dinero
                td
                  select
                    option
                      each usuario in ListUsuario
                        option(value=usuario.Sk_Codigo_Usuario) #{usuario.Sk_Codigo_Usuario}
                td
                  input(type="checkbox")
```

Comment: en esta linea tienes un `./` de mas, `var config = require('.././database/config');`, no da errores pero para que sepas ;)

Comment: anyade la etiqueta `sql`, o el nombre del modulo que usas

Comment: Si el jade no es problema, solo es la consulta sql, puedes borrar el codigo jade innecesario

Comment: no he trabajado con consultas sql, y no se que modulo usas pero puede que el problema sea que `sql.close()` es asyncronico, asi que se cierra la conexion justo despues de de intentar volver a conectarse, revisa si `sql.close` acepta un callback y asi esperar a que se cierre la conexion antes de volver a abrirla

Comment: uso el modulo mssql

Comment: Revisa que las dos consulta SQL funcionen correctamente desde la consola o desde una pestaña de querys. luego colocalas aqui.

Comment: La consulta funciona, lo que pasa es que al llenar los datos solo me escoge el 2 y es donde me saca error que no existe `each Articulos in ListArticulos`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema esta claro, tienes que esperar a que acaben las dos consultas para renderear la pagina, estas llamando a `res.render` dos veces, y solo debes hacer esto una vez por `request`, revise el modulo mssql y me parecio que trabajaba con promises, en ese caso tienes que hacer las dos peticiones a sql y guardar el resultado, pero no renderear la pagina cada vez, sino al final de las dos peticiones renderear la pagina con el valor de la dos peticiones, en la pregunta ambos usan `ListArticulos` pero por el comentario supongo que uno es `ListUsuarios`, entonces despues de que tienes todos los datos harias:

```
res.render('menu/analisisDetallado', { 
    ListArticulos: firstSqlRequest,
    ListUsuarios: secondSqlRequest,
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Buenas, te recomiendo usar los módulos **async**, **mssql** y **debug**, podrás simplificar mucho tu código, y con el módulo **debug**, sólo te saldrán mensajes en la consola cuando lo ejecutes.

Así cómo poner tus consultas todas juntas en un fichero.

Te paso un ejemplo, dónde ejecuto dos funciones con 5 o 6 consultas a varias bases de datos y una consulta directa.

```
router.get('/:id', function(req, res, next) {
    var reqAx = new sql.Request(dbConfig.config)
    async.waterfall([
        function(callback){
            auxFunctions.getInfo1(machineID, 'empresa', function(array1){
                callback(null, Array1);
            });
        },
        function(array1, callback){
            reqAx.query(qrys.qry_messages('grupoX', id,'ent'))
            .then(function (messages){
                callback(null, oftArrayFullInfo, messages)
            })
        },
        function(array1, messages, callback){
            auxFunctions.getInfo2(id, 'empresa', array1, function(array2){
                callback(null, array1, messages, array2);
            });
        }   
    ],
    function(err, array1, messages, array2){
        if(err) {debug('****** ERROR ASYNC: \n %s', err); }
        else{
            if (array1.length>0){
                res.render('info', {title: 'Info', array1, array2, messages});}
            else{ res.redirect('/'); }
        }
    });
});
```